# Can NodeJS prefer IPv6 DNS lookups by default?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, ipv6

I am developing multiple TypeScript (NodeJS 14) client applications (all Dockerized). Most of the HTTP requests are made using [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios), but not exclusively.

By default, all DNS queries resolve to IPv4 addresses, so all HTTP traffic is over IPv4 as well.

I could specify the exact IPv6 address for each and every one of the requests I make - but I'd like to find a way to have these apps opt for IPv6 DNS resolution, preferably with as little code changes as possible. Maybe a `tsnode.json` modification or some other flag that affects NodeJS at the "root" level?

Comment: Pretty sure you'll find that this is an OS level policy and not something you can override at the Node.js level.

Comment: @Quentin Then I should have mentioned that these are Dockerized apps. Can this be achieved at the Docker level? BTW looking at PRs like [this one](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/39987), it seems like `node` does have a "say" in the process.

Comment: That's well beyond my Docker skill level. I strongly suggest adding suitable docker related tags to your question!

Comment: The latest Happy Eyeball algorithm is detailed in _[RFC 8305, Happy Eyeballs Version 2: Better Connectivity Using Concurrency](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8305)_. The purpose is to prefer IPv6 without causing undue delay: "_The Happy Eyeballs algorithm of racing connections to resolved addresses has several stages to avoid delays to the user whenever possible, while preferring the use of IPv6._"

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure You are looking for `dns.setDefaultResultOrder(order)`
which allows you to set dns lookup priority: `ipv4first` and `verbatim`.

https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnssetdefaultresultorderorder

Comment: Works great for preferring ipv4 (aka `node --dns-result-order=ipv4first`) but OP wants ipv6, no such option here